# How to configure Quartz DataSource URL dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, cloud-foundry

I have spring application which runs in cloud foundry. Also, I am using spring-cloud-connector (CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator) to retrieve URLs for various services, such as MariaDB, Redis, etc. I need to use Quartz for scheduling and I am following docs (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html), where 'org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL' is hardcoded in property file. I need to be able to set it on runtime. Is there a way ? Or Quartz can only be configured through property file ? I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create a Quartz `StdSchedulerFactory` from a `java.util.Properties` instance, which might give you the flexibility you're looking for.

For more details, see the Javadoc here:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#StdSchedulerFactory(java.util.Properties)